# If $b\mid a$ and $b\mid a-c$ then $b\mid c$ proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I was doing my homework in algebra and I'm not sure if I'm right. Basically, I have to show that $b\mid c$ is true as $b\mid a$ and $b\mid (a-c)$ are true (transitivity).

$
\begin{align*}
b\mid a \leftrightarrow a = b\cdot k \\
b\mid a-c \leftrightarrow a-c = b\cdot k
\end{align*}
$

With the system of equations shown above, I added them up and it resulted on the following equation.

$
\begin{align*}
a + (a-c) &= 2b\cdot k \\
2a - c &= b \cdot 2k && 2a,2b \in \mathbb{Z} \\
\beta - c &= b \cdot \alpha && \text{implying } b\mid\beta - c \\
\end{align*}
$

Is it right?

Comment: You probably want to differentiate the various $k$...  For example, $k_1,k_2,k_3,\dots$

Comment: Should I use another variable name for k?

Comment: There is really only one scenario where $a=bk$ and also $a-c=bk$, where $c=0$...

Comment: That's one thing I saw, but I couldn't go further than that.

Comment: That isn't transitivity . . .

Comment: You probably want to subtract $a-c$ from $a$ to get your result.

Comment: Got it @abiessu, how couldn't see that? Much thanks, should I answer my own question?

Comment: @Shaun, it sure is.

Comment: @abiessu that's why you told me to differentiate the different k...

Comment: Transitivity is, if $x\mid y$ and $y\mid z$, then $x\mid z$.

Comment: That's what I wrote in a very peculiar way? $b|a$ and $b|a-c$ then $b|c$

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: So what is that?

Comment: I don't know. ${}$

Comment: Since $x=a-c$ and $y=a$ are multiples of $b$ the so is there difference $x-y$ (an integral linear combination of $x$ and $y)$, by the linked dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that follows, as explained in the comments:

$
\begin{align*}
a = b \cdot k_1 && \text{*} \\
a - c = b \cdot k_2 && \text{**}
\end{align*}
$

Subtracting $*$ from $**$ we have the following solution

$
\begin{align*}
a - c - a &= b \cdot k_2 - b \cdot k_1 \\
- c &= b \cdot (k_2 - k_1) \\
- c &= - b \cdot (- k_2 + k_1) && -k_2+k_1 =l , l\ \in \mathbb{Z} \\
-c &= -b \cdot l && \cdot(-1) \\
c  &= b \cdot l
\end{align*}
$

So we have that indeed $b|c$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $b\mid a$ and $b\mid a-c$. Then there exist integers $k,l$ such that $a=bk$ and $a-c=bl$. Now $bk-c=bl$, so that $c=bk-bl=b(k-l)$; but $k-l$ is an integer, so, by definition, $b\mid c$.